# Docker mythril can't connect to Ganache or local .sol contracts

Tags: solidity, docker, mythril

Has anyone here used the docker version of Mythril (https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril) and can give me a hint on how to make it work? I only get:

```
$ docker run mythril/myth -xa 0xc0ed3c3c725c6f3202c13fb49fb7fddb1385e62d29279a0a9a170b5251fb10a6 --rpc ganache
Could not connect to RPC server. Make sure that your node is running and that RPC parameters are set correctly.

$ docker run mythril/myth -x MyContract.sol
Input file not found: MyContract.sol
```

My Ganache is running my Truffle unit tests fine and MyContract.sol is in the current working directory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading up on Docker, I found the following solutions.

To connect to a local RPC, use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`. For example, Ganache listens on port 7545 by default:

```
docker run mythril/myth -xa 0xadf6E506c4243E9fb25EA6517017E63a2eaEBB0e --rpc host.docker.internal:7545
```

To analyze a local .sol file, you have to mount the directory where the file is located. If you want to analyze `MyContract.sol` in your current working directory, run the following command:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/working-dir mythril/myth -x /working-dir/MyContract.sol
```

Comment: Hej Svante. Jeg faldt over din profil herinde og blev imponeret over din viden om Ethereum. Jeg ville elske at drøfte en ting med dig. Kan jeg kontakte dig privat?